# Getting Stylus to work with Express and Node

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, stylus

I am new to node, express, stylus, ejs (the whole bundle) and am having trouble getting stylus to work.

I have a directory that contains:

app.js

public/main.styl

views/index.ejs

Here is my app.js code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var stylus = require('stylus');

    app.configure(function(){
      app.use(stylus.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
    });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.listen(80);
```

When I go to localhost my index.ejs file has rendered but it doesn't contain any style. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Are there any good tutorials for getting started with stylus? Apologies if this is too vague. Thanks!

Comment: If you post the contents of your `index.ejs` I'm sure we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the URL in the `<link>` for your stylesheet is "/main.css" and not "public/main.css" or anything like that; otherwise stylus will actually be looking for public/public/main.styl.

Comment: I had no idea it compiles the file upon hitting the url. I had the wrong path in my jade template and could figure out why on earth it wasn't compiling the stylus file.